# How to parse a string in brackets and double quotes KQL

Tags: azure, grafana, kql

Fairly simple question but due to how new I am at KQL I am struggling to figure out how to do this properly. I want to parse a string that has ["*name*"]. Currently I am doing `| parse Tags_s * "[" Tags` and then just end up getting "*name*"] as a result. I tried parsing in the quotes but every time I do I just bring back empty data. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
print Tags_s = '["name"]'
| parse Tags_s with '["' tag_name '"]'
```

| Tags_s | tag_name |
| --- | --- |
| ["name"] | name |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/dumarkovdev.westeurope/databases/mydb?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAysoyswrUQhJTC%20OL1awVVCPVspLzE1VilXn5apRKEgsKk6FSZZnlmSA5NUVShLT40GqFNSB6gA%20w4kTQQAAAA==)

Comment: This is a direct answer to your question; however, I assume that you might have multiple tags, which will require a different solution. 
If indeed needed, please feel free to open a new question for that.