# How to parse a table of strings from log analytics string in brackets and double quotes KQL

Tags: azure, grafana, kql, azure-log-analytics

Fairly simple question but due to how new I am at KQL I am struggling to figure out how to do this properly. I want to parse a string from a table that has ["name"]. Problem is there are about 28,000 different strings and they are all unique. I just need to pull whatever the string is that's between the double quotes and brackets. Currently I am doing `| parse Tags_s * "[" Tags` and then just end up getting "name"] as a result. I tried parsing in the quotes but every time I do I just bring back empty data. So somehow I need to parse 28,000 individual strings and only pull the actual word out from the quotes and brackets all under the Tags_s dataset.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse a string in brackets and double quotes KQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72884055/how-to-parse-a-string-in-brackets-and-double-quotes-kql)

Comment: Please avoid posting the same question multiple times

Comment: You said to post a new question if it was based off multiple data items

Comment: "This is a direct answer to your question; however, I assume that you might have multiple tags, which will require a different solution. If indeed needed, please feel free to open a new question for that."

Comment:  multiple tags in a single Tags_s, not multiple rows